# Using SQL to Split Dates

Tags: sql, loops

I have a start date and an End date for different records of data in a file. The dates span over five years. At the moment I am looking to split the dates using one year intervals from the start date to the end date.

How can I use sql to do this so it loops through the file containing the records and do the split automatically to insert into a different table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean loop through a table (data is already in a table?) or do you really need to read the file with SQL too?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't do this at all, and if you *did* do this, you wouldn't do it with SQL. What are you *really* trying to do? Splitting dates into different tables isn't a problem; it's a questionable *solution* to a problem. What's the *real* problem?

Comment: Data is in an excel file with start and end dates. I can extract this data into a sql table. I am now looking to split the dates and then move the result to a new sql table ready to use.

Comment: Edit your question, and include the structure of the Excel file. And, again, what's the *real* problem? ("I want to split the dates" isn't a problem.)

Comment: I have thousands of records in a sql table. They have column A start date and column B end date. Eg. Start date  01/01/2005 end date 31/12/2014. I will like this date for a record to look like this start date 01/01/2005 end date 31/12/2005 and another to start 01/01/2006/31/12/2006 .......until 31/12/2014 it doesn't matter where the data is stored...it's in a sql table and I need the script to do this split. I'd like this script to loop through other records in this table and split them as well. A stored procedure maybe? Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a loop.

You should do something like this.

```
SELECT t.info, YEAR(t.Date)
FROM yourtable AS t
WHERE t.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: This won't run since t.info isn't in your group by or an aggregate

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch "annualized" subsets of rows without writing them to other tables. And generally, you *should* avoid writing them to other tables. Writing rows to other tables quickly becomes a maintenance headache when data in the original table changes. Depending on the other data in the table, writing rows to other tables can make it hard--if not impossible--to run accurate aggregate queries (queries using min(), max(), sum(), avg(), etc.).

Let's make a table.

```
create table test (
  start_date date,
  end_date date
  );

-- Start in 2005; lasts more than a year.
insert into test values ('2005-03-02', '2014-12-31');

-- Start in 2005; lasts less than a year.
insert into test values ('2005-03-02', '2005-10-18');

-- Not in 2005.
insert into test values ('2006-02-15', '2008-11-13');
```

To get all the "2005" rows, you can run this query. I'm assuming you want the actual value of start_date if that happens to be later than 2005-01-01.

```
select 
  case when '2005-01-01' between start_date and end_date
       then '2005-01-01' else start_date
  end start_date,
  case when '2005-12-31' between start_date and end_date
       then '2005-12-31' else end_date
  end end_date
from test
where 2005 between extract(year from start_date) and extract(year from end_date)
order by start_date, end_date;
```

```
start_date  end_date
--
2005-03-02  2005-10-18
2005-03-02  2005-12-31
```

Get all the "2006" rows in a similar way.

```
select 
  case when '2006-01-01' between start_date and end_date
       then '2006-01-01' else start_date
  end start_date,
  case when '2006-12-31' between start_date and end_date
       then '2006-12-31' else end_date
  end end_date
from test
where 2006 between extract(year from start_date) and extract(year from end_date)
order by start_date, end_date;
```

```
start_date  end_date
--
2006-01-01  2006-12-31
2006-02-15  2006-12-31
```

Of course, you can wrap each of these statements in a `create view` clause. You should *probably* do that.